# Lua event handler

Tags: lua

Does lua have an "event handler" build in or does it have a lib available to do that?

So that, an example, when "a = 100" an event happens.

Something else rather than using:

```
while true do
 if a == 100 then
   [...]
   break;
 end
end
```

Or simply adding a sleep to it. The "while true do" is just an example but its a terrible one.

Comment: Well. Basically check on a value and if it meets the requirements an event is called. Just not doing it in a way of "ifs" or like the above "while true do" because it isn't suitable. The requirement can be met at any moment, not a specific part or time where I can call an if statement, for example. I hope that explains it a bit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Lua operates in a single-thread, so any checking must be explicitly performed by your code.

The act of performing code immediately upon a variable changing is known as "watching".

If you are programming in an environment where a set of code is run every *frame* (such as a game), you can check manually.
For example:

```
WatchedVariables = {
    a = 5,
    b = 22,
}
WatchedVariables_cache = {}
for k,v in pairs(WatchedVariables) do
    WatchedVariables_cache[k] = v
end

function OnFrame()
    print("NEXT FRAME! (possibly 1 second later or something)")
    for k,v in pairs(WatchedVariables) do
        local v_old = WatchedVariables_cache[k]
        if v ~= v_old then
            -- this is the "callback"
            print(tostring(k).." changed from "..tostring(v_old).." to "..tostring(v))

            WatchedVariables_cache[k] = v
        end
     end
 end

 function SomeFunctionThatOperatesSomeTime()
     print("about to change a, brother!")
     WatchedVariables.a = -7
     print("a is changed")
 end
```

Upon the next frame, the callback code (the print) will be executed.
The disadvantage of this approach is that the callback code is not printed **immediately** after `WatchedVariables.a` is set to `-7`, that is: the output will be:

```
about to change a, brother!
a is changed
NEXT FRAME! (possibly 1 second later or something)
a changed from 5 to -7
```

To prevent this potentially undesired behaviour, a *setter* function can be used, for example:

```
MyObject = {
    _private_a = 5,
    set_a = function(self, new_value_of_a)
        self._private_a = 5
        -- callback code
        print("a set to "..tostring(new_value_of_a))
    end,
    get_a = function(self)
        return self._private_a
    end
}

function SomeFunctionThatOperatesSomeTime()
     print("about to change a, brother!")
     MyObject:set_a(-7)
     print("a is changed")
 end
```

The output of this code shows that the callback runs immediately:

```
about to change a, brother!
a set to -7
a is changed
```

To make this more comfortable, Lua provides **metatables** that make such behaviour transparent to the programmer.
Example:

```
MyObject = {
    __privates = {
        a = 5,
    }
}
MyObject_meta = {
    __index = function(self, k)
        return rawget(self, "__privates")[k]
    end,
    __newindex = function(self, k, v)
        rawget(self, "__privates")[k] = v
        -- callback code
        print("a set to "..tostring(v))
    end,
}
setmetatable(MyObject, MyObject_meta)

function SomeFunctionThatOperatesSomeTime()
     print("about to change a, brother!")
     MyObject.a = -7
     print("a is changed")
 end
```

The output of this code will be the same as the previous example:

```
about to change a, brother!
a set to -7
a is changed
```

Here's an implementation for your example case:

```
MyObject = {
    __privates = {
        a = 5,
    }
    __private_callback = function(self, k, ov, v)
        if k == "a" and v == "100" then
            print("a is 100!")
        end
    end
}
MyObject_meta = {
    __index = function(self, k)
        return rawget(self, "__privates")[k]
    end,
    __newindex = function(self, k, v)
        local privates = rawget(self, "__privates")
        local ov = privates[k]
        privates[k] = v
        rawget(self, "__private_callback")(self, k, ov, v)
    end,
}
setmetatable(MyObject, MyObject_meta)

function SomeFunctionThatOperatesSomeTime()
     MyObject.a = -7 -- prints nothing
     MyObject.a = 100 -- prints "a is 100!"
     MyObject.a = 22 -- prints nothing
 end
```

*Why are the variables `__privates` and `__private_callback` prefixed with two underscores?* It is convention to prefix private members that should not be accessed in typical programming situations with two underscores. If you familiar with object-oriented methodology and it's implementation in languages such as Java and C++, you will understand how it is similar to the `private` and `protected` keywords.

If you are familiar with the C# language, you may see how the `set_a`/`get_a` and metatable implementations are similar to accessors (`set`/`get`).

Comment: Great answer. This is exactly what I thought it would turn out concerning the metatables.

Comment: Happy to help. Just be careful with whose `__privates` you touch... you don't know what you'll catch.